# Automatically Get Bitcoin Difficulty, Bitcoins/Block, Exchange Rate Statistics

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, server, services

What can I do to programmatically get statistics such as current Bitcoin difficulty, Bitcoin award per block, USD/BTC exchange rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get...

- difficulty from: http://blockexplorer.com/q/getdifficulty
- reward per block from: http://blockexplorer.com/q/bcperblock
- exchange rate from: http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/weighted_prices.json

  - or from: http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json

You might want to read [this](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/).

See list of other bitcoin stats [here](http://blockexplorer.com/q).

Comment: The first two links are no longer available (404)